# Does set difference distribute over set intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove that, if $A, B$ and $C$ are sets, then $$A-(B\cap C)=(A-B)\cap(A-C).$$  However, I think that either I have made an error in my working, or the wording of the problem contains a typographical error.

My working so far is as follows: $$\begin{align}x\in(A-(B\cap C)) &\iff (x\in A)\wedge(x\not\in(B\cap C))\\ &\iff(x\in A)\wedge((x\not\in B)\vee(x\not\in C))\\ &\iff((x\in A)\wedge(x\not\in B))\vee((x\in A)\wedge(x\not\in C))\\ &\iff(x\in(A-B))\vee(x\in(A-C))\\ &\iff x\in((A-B)\cup(A-C)) \end{align}$$

First line to second line: by De Morgan's Law.
Second line to third line: by distributivity of set intersection over set union.
Third line to fourth line: by definitions of intersection and set difference.

If my working is correct, then I have shown that $$A-(B\cap C)=(A-B)\cup(A-C).$$
Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct, it's the union.

Comment: This is basically De Morgan's Law for sets, with $\cap$ and $\cup$ mirroring $\wedge$ and $\vee$, respectively, and negation $\neg$ given by $A\setminus \cdot$. (So yes, you got it right, it should be union)

Comment: If $x \notin B \cup C \Rightarrow x \notin B \cap C$.

Comment: You have proven that $A-(B \cap C) \subseteq (A-B) \cup (A-C)$. Now you have to show that $(A-B) \cup(A-C) \subseteq A-(B \cap C)$ as well, just like @evinda has done below.

Comment: @Marcelo Uchimura: don't the if and only if symbols take care of this?

Comment: @CKKOY Unfortunately not. You have to go one way and then the way back separately.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura No, CKKOY is correct. "$x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B$" implies that "$A = B$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x \in (A-B) \cap (A-C) \Rightarrow (x \in A \wedge  x \notin B) \wedge (x \in A \wedge x \notin C) \\ \Rightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin B \wedge x \notin C \Rightarrow x \in A-(B \cup C) \Rightarrow  x \in A-(B \cap C)$$

$$x \in A-(B \cap C) \Rightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin B \cap C \Rightarrow x \in A-(B \cap C)$$

Comment: Ah - so the problem was not incorrectly worded.  Rather, both of the following hold: $x\in A-(B\cap C)\iff x\in(A-B)\cap(A-C)$ and $x\in A-(B\cap C)\iff x\in(A-B)\cup(A-C)$.  Have I understood correctly?

Comment: -1 The last step, $x \in A - (B \cup C) \Leftrightarrow x \in A - (B \cap C)$, is completely invalid.  Take for example $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1\}$, $C = \{2\}$.  The "$\Leftrightarrow$" can only be an "$\Rightarrow$", which breaks the proof.  @CKKOY Your book **is** in fact wrong, it fails for the case I just mentioned.  To answer your last question, $x \in Y \cap Z \Rightarrow x \in Y \cup Z$ *(because $Y \cap Z \subseteq Y \cup Z$)*, so your first statement implies your second.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Which last step are you referring to?

Comment: @CKKOY [The one from before the edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1261960/1).  The post is now "correct", but it does not actually prove what you're asking since it's not bi-directional.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You are correct.  I will point this out to my lecturer.

Answer (score 5):

You are right. As an other proof:
$$A-(B\cap C)=A\cap (B\cap C)^c= A\cap (B^c\cup C^c)=$$
$$(A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap C^c)=(A-B)\cup(A-C).$$